# Bootstrap Tooltips Disappear Upon Sorting Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have included some Bootstrap tooltips (indicated by glyphicons) in my table (http://jsfiddle.net/mademoiselletse/bypbqboe/66/) by adding the following tag directly into my table cell:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-title="this is a tooltip glyphicon"></i>
```

I initialize the tooltips by triggering `tooltipExe ()` every time the table is loaded (line 56, 82, 109, 117), defined as follows:

```
function tooltipExe () {
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
};
```

While it works perfectly when the table is loaded, the Bootstrap tooltip effect within the table cells strangely disappear once I sort the table.  I looked through the [Bootstrap JS documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) and the forum but couldn't find anything helpful.  Does anyone know what might cause such disappearance?  I would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: can you put your code in fiddler?

Comment: Sounds like you may need to re initialize tooltips after sorting? Which may not be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Bootstrap must be doing something that breaks your tooltip binding. Run it on the sort callback:

```
$table.on('sort.bs.table', function () {
    tooltipExe();
});
```

Update: The sort event didn't work, possibly since it fires at the beginning of the sort operation, so I went with `all.bs.table`. I see that an after-sort event [has been requested](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/297).

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bypbqboe/67/)**

Update again: I see from that Github thread that you could use the `post-body.bs.table` event to reduce the number of function calls.

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/bypbqboe/68/)**

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 4, the code posted below works for me. When I click on a table column to sort the table by that column, the tooltips work fine after sorting if I add the function below that fires after the table is re-drawn.

```
<table id="smmrytbl" class="compact striped table-hover dt-responsive display"></table>
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#smmrytbl').DataTable( {
    [...]   
    } );
});
$('#smmrytbl').on( 'draw.dt', function () {        
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('update');
});
</script>
```

All my tooltips are set as shown in the example below:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title="5<sup>th</sup> Percentile">42</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through this problem today

If you want tooltips to be back, you need to fire them again, (or regenerate them) via a `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

When they're gone, or you think they should be there, if you execute `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` from your browser console, they should be back.

I tried using `click` or `mouseup` events. Even `post-body.bs.table` or `all.bs.table` weren't enougth.

It's all about DOM update, and so, firing code at the right time, or at least at a good time.

Here is my solution, or mostly a hack, using `setTimeout()` to give some time to the DOM to be updated.

```
$(function () {
    tooltipExe();
    $('#table-id th').click(function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            tooltipExe();
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Timeout delay, is up to you: enough time for machine to update the DOM, but not enough for human to point elements with tooltip!